# Proving "If there exists a line containing exactly $n$ points, then any line contains exactly $n$ points" from basic axioms of incidence

Tags: geometry, logic, axioms

I have to show that the following theorem can be proven using the axioms cited below:

> If there exists a line that contains exactly $n$ points, then any line contains exactly n points, and any point has exactly $n$ lines that contain it.

The axioms are the following:

1. There exist at least one line.
2. If L is a line, then there exist at least 3 points on L
3. If L is a line, then there exists one point that is not on L
4. Given any two points P and Q, there exists one and only one line that contains both P and Q
5. If L and M are two lines, then there exists at least one point P that is contained in both L and M.

**My effort.** I have thought about using induction to prove the statement, but I don't know how to start.

Can you please provide me an overview of a proof of this theorem? Thank you so much for your time!

***UPDATE***
I managed to show that every point is contained in at least $n$ lines, but I have no idea on how to show that it is contained in **exactly** $n$ lines, which is what the theorem states.

Comment: A line contains "exactly" $n$ points means it contains at least $n$ points but does not contain more than $n$ points.

Comment: thanks, I know that, I just think it makes the proof more complicated, it would probably be easier to show that a line contains "at least n points", but I really don't know how to put it together

Comment: You might be interested in the "Fano plane" which has seven points in all and satisfies your axioms for the case $n=3.$ [You can google the quoted reference to get details.] So it can't be shown from the axioms that there is a line with more than 3 points. Of course you are to *assume* there is a line with exactly $n$ points and derive the fact about points being on exactly $n$ lines. I guess if you dropped "exactly" in both parts and replaced it with "at least" then it might be easier, but then some more work would be needed to derive the "exactly" version from that.

Comment: I don't understand Axiom 5. It ignores the possibility of parallel lines. Are we talking about non-euclidean geometries?

Comment: you are correct, this is an abstract geometry, It's noneuclidian

Comment: @coffeemath. I am confused. How can a line not contain more than $n$ points? A line contains infinitely many points, if there are only $n$ points in a line then that doesn't even create a line, it creates a collection of points. **Please clarify**.

Comment: @RounakSarkar The subject discussed in this question is *finite* projective geometries like the Fano plane. These only have a finite number of points in the whole space. None of their lines contain infinitely many points.

Comment: @RounakSarkar this is an abstract geometry. Keep in mind a "line" is a primitive or undefined term in this context. I would recommend you check out the first chapter of "Introduction to the Foundations of Mathematics" by Wilder.

Comment: Can you prove this just for $n=2$ for example? Or can you share your proof of how you proved that every point is contained in at least $n$ different lines?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Given there is a line with $n$ points $x_1, \dots x_n$,then for any point $a$ not on this line, we can use (4) and get $n$ lines $a x_1, \dots, a x_n$, which all contain $a$. (Also the case $n=2$ is probably excluded because of (2))

Comment: @Lereau Makes sense, thanks, and I see that these are distinct lines because if two lines $ax_1,ax_n$ coincided then $x_1,x_n$ would be contained in two lines, one of which contains $a$ and the other which does not, which is a contradiction to $(4)$. That makes $n$ distinct lines. Also, $n=2$ is excluded, I'll replace it with $n=4$ and maybe see what can be done w.r.t the exactness situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, let's go for it. I will use the axiom numbering present in the question. *lower case* letters represent points, *UPPER CASE* letters represent lines, because... $42$.

We use the notation $p \in L$ for a point $p$ and a line $L$ if $p$ is contained in $L$, and $p \notin L$ if it's not contained in $L$. For two lines $L$ and $M$, $L \cap M$ denotes the collection of points contained in both $L$ and $M$ i.e. where $L$ and $M$ intersect.

---

We first improve axiom $5$.

> If $L \neq M$ are two distinct lines, then $|L \cap M| = 1$. (Note : axiom $5$ would say $|L \cap M| \geq 1$).

Proof : Suppose $p \neq q \in L \cap M$. By axiom $4$, there exists a unique line $L'$ such that $p,q \in L'$, but then $L,M$ are two distinct candidates which fulfill this criteria. This contradiction proves that $|L \cap M| \leq 1$, which combined with axiom $5$ proves that $|L \cap M| = 1$. $\blacksquare$

---

Next, we devise the following "projective" strategy : let's imagine looking at two different lines , from a point not on either of them. Then, each point on one of the lines "corresponds" to a point on the other line, as the two points that are in the "same direction" when viewed from that exterior point. This correspondence can be proved to be a bijection, so that all lines have the same number of points! I would suggest drawing a diagram , probably I'll attach one later on if I get the time.

---

So we begin with the first idea , of proving the existence of the exterior point.

> For two lines $L \neq M$ there is a point $r \notin L , r \notin M$.

Proof : This one is nice! We know that $|L \cap M| = 1$ so let $q$ be that intersection point. From axiom $2$, Pick a $p \in L$ and a $p' \in M$ such that $p \neq q, p' \neq q$. From axiom $4$, consider the unique line $N$ that passes through $p$ and $p'$. By axiom $2$, there is a point $r \neq p , r \neq p', r \in N$. Can you prove that $r \notin L , r \notin M$?$\blacksquare$

> If $r \in L$, then $r \in N \cap L$ and $p \in N \cap L$ and $r \neq p$, which means $|N \cap L| > 2$, a contradiction as $N \neq L$ , $p'$ being contained in the former but not in the latter. Similarly we can contradict $r \in M$.

---

Now we are ready to "view $L$ and $M$" from $r$. Since $L$ and $M$ are "collections" of points, I'll treat them as sets and use functional notation. Let $p \in L$ and let $L_p$ be the unique line connecting $p$ and $r$. Since $L_p \neq M$ (as $r \notin M$) we know that $|L_p \cap M| = 1$. Let that point of intersection be $p'$. We define the function $f: L \to M$ by $f(p) = p'$. Clearly $f$ is well defined by what we've already written.

> $f : L \to M$ as described above is an injective map, and hence $M$ contains at least as many points as $L$.

Proof : Suppose $f(p_1) = f(p_2)$. Let $L_{p_1}$ be the unique line joining $p_1$ and $r$, and $L_{p_2}$ be the unique line joining $p_2$ and $r$.

Since $f(p_1)=f(p_2)$, this point lies on both $L_{p_1}$ and $L_{p_2}$, but is distinct from $r$ which also lies on $L_{p_1}$ and $L_{p_2}$. Thus $|L_{p_1}\cap L_{p_2}| > 1$, which is a contradiction unless $L_{p_1} = L_{p_2} = L'$. So $L'$ contains both $p_1$ and $p_2$, but these points are also contained in $L$! If $p_1\neq p_2$ then $|L'\cap L| > 1$, a contradiction since $L'$ contains $r$ but $L$ does not. Hence, $p_1=p_2$ and injectivity is proved! $\blacksquare$

Note that the intersection point of $L$ and $M$ actually maps to itself under $f$.

---

But then, we can flip the roles of $L$ and $M$ above ,retain the point $r$ and obtain a function $f' : M \to L$ which is injective by the same logic above. Thus, we get that the map $f: L \to M$ is in fact *bijective*, and :

> Corollary : All lines have $n$ points.

Proof : Suppose $T$ is the line which has $n$ points and $T'$ is any other line. Then $f : T \to T'$ as described earlier is bijective, hence $T'$ has $n$ points as well.$\blacksquare$

---

We now switch to the second part of the story.

---

The question is, how do we plan to do this? Well, think about this way : earlier, we "saw" two different lines through a point not on them. Now, we are going to see the lines through a point, from a line that doesn't pass through that point.

For this, we need that line , of course!

> For a point $p$, there is a line $L$ with $p \notin L$.

Proof : If there is no line passing through $p$, then we are done by axiom $1$. So let $L$ be a line passing through $p$. By axiom $3$, pick a $q \notin L$. By axiom $2$ , let $r \in L, r \neq p$ . By axiom $4$, let $L'$ be the unique line passing through $r$ and $q$. Then $p \notin L'$, because if $p \in L'$ then $q \in L', q \notin L$, but $r,p \in L \cap L'$, contradiction. So $L'$ is the desired line. $\blacksquare$

---

Let's make every line that passes through $p$ now intersect $L'$ at various points. This is how $L'$ "sees" $p$, and it turns out this is magnificently good!

To make this more precise, let $\mathcal F$ be the collection of lines $L$ with $p \in L$. We will define a function $F : \mathcal F \to L'$ as follows : for $L \in \mathcal F$, we know that $L \neq L'$ since $p \in L, p \notin L'$. Thus, $|L \cap L'| = 1$, and that intersection point is $f(L)$.

> $F : \mathcal F \to L'$ is a bijection.

Proof: We need to show injectivity and surjectivity.

###### Injectivity

Suppose that $F(L_1) = F(L_2)$. Then, $L_1$ and $L_2$ intersect $L'$ at the same point, but also pass through $p$. Hence, by axiom $4$ applied to these points, we know that $L_1=L_2$.

###### Surjectivity

This is again following from axiom $4$, since if $r \in L'$ then $r \neq p$ so there is a line $L$ that passes through $r$ and $p$, which means that $L \in \mathcal F$ and $F(L) = r$, as desired.

Hence, $F$ is *bijective*!$\blacksquare$.

---

Corollary : As $F$ is bijective, for every point $p$ we have that $\mathcal F$ contains $n$ lines, since $L'$ contains $n$ points.

Comment: Note : I will not respond to feedback immediately as I will be asleep for 7-8 hours from this time. I will surely reply to feedback, thank you dear commenter for your patience.

Comment: You really take the time to answer questions. You're the perfect user.

Comment: @RounakSarkar Thanks, it probably grew out of some kind of realization that I like to take my time. If I have to be honest , diversity is king! We need answerers of all kinds :  fast answerers, hint givers, long explanations, experts in different disciplines and so on. We also need good question askers of different kinds. The only thing we need to make sure is that as much of the guidelines is followed as possible. MSE has space for everybody to flourish, together.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon    just curious... how long did it take you to put this proof together?

Comment: @DougL Probably 2 hours to put it together and 1 hour to tidy up the notation and so on. I took some inspiration from Wilder : Actually, Wilder has a different axiom 5 if I'm not wrong, but I looked at his first exercise and his corollaries, that something could be made out of the "viewing a line from a point" perspective, and thankfully I could get through this somewhat quicker than I usually get through an answer.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon you're a brilliant thinker, I'd love to follow you on SM to know more about you if that's ok

Comment: @DougL Thank you very much. I will look forward to further interactions with you on MSE!